# Como consumir API Rest Django utilizando angular?

Tags: python, django, angular

Soy nuevo en python y estoy empezando a desarrollar una aplicacion web con django,  me gustaria utilizar angular en el frontend pero no he encontrado un ejemplo sencillo en donde me expliquen como lograr integrarlos correctamente.

Cualquier recomendación me seria de mucha ayuda... gracias

Answer (score 0):

Desde angular debes realizar llamadas por ajax para obtener la información de la API. te adjunto la documentación donde puedes verlo [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)